# How properly use array here?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

i have  a problem with my code, i cant use my array properly, for some reason its blank, here is my code

```
    function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl ('sheet url');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("new project")
  var v1 = sheet.getLastRow()
  Logger.log(v1);
  var v2 = sheet.getLastColumn()
  Logger.log(v2);
  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() -1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  Logger.log(data);
  
  

    for (var i = 1; i <= data.length; ++i) 
      {
        var data1 = sheet.getRange(i,1,1,13).getValues()
        Logger.log(i);
        Logger.log(data1); 
        var cell = data[i][9]; //this array is a problem
        Logger.log(cell);
        if (cell ==="") {
          Logger.log('blank cell');
        }
        
      }  
      }
```

so this is why its a problem : [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCBUM.png)

this how my sheet looks like : [sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MYaL.png)

screen of my error: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEBq7.png)

as you can see its just empty, idk if its even null, please help

Comment: Can you show what your data looks like? How many columns, rows and any blank cells in there? Can you paste the whole Logger report please? And what's the expected output?

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk i added how my sheet looks like, and data is basicaly reading from sheet without first row

Comment: My start row is 2 also.

Comment: @Cooper i will be honnest, it will take me so much time to understand your code, its not rly comment about you but about my stupidity :)

Comment: I gather that you have never used Array Methods or Arrow Function Notation

Comment: @Cooper me not good :( me realy stupid :( but realy why -1 in "sh.getLastRow() - 1"?

Comment: Because the third parameter is the number of rows not the number of the last row.  More generally you could say that is will always be sh.getLastRow() - startRow + 1

Comment: Your reading column index 9, which is actually your 10th column, which is "Pidgruppa", which is mostly blank

Comment: No I'm reading column 9 which is index 8 in the data array.

Comment: @Cooper yes, it helped a little, so basicaly, number of rows should be -1 cuz first is 0? thanks, i will observe your code more

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk yes this is why i check if its emty in each row

Comment: No the number of row is always Sheet.getLastRow() - start Row + 1

Comment: And the start row is 2 in this case which is sh.getLastRow() -2 +1

Comment: @Cooper isnt rows in google sheet starts from 1, not 0? its -1+1 then ?

Comment: Your starting row for data is row 2

Comment: @Cooper oh, you right, because its not from 0 -1 from start and -1 because of start from 2

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure I'm right about this.  Go Study it for a while.

Comment: @Cooper as im tried your code, i find out that -1 dont work, and leaving it as it is with start on 2 row works just fine

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying both of my codes begin collecting data on line two.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of the problem

Comment: @Cooper i litteraly added 3 screenshots

Comment: If I can't reproduce the problem then it's difficult to solve.

Comment: @Cooper no joke, just create sheet, click add script, and paste this code

Comment: @Cooper this script works with custom sheet, only thing to change is 9 in if and array, and 13 in data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, reason why i had a problem, i used 'i' as a number of a column, while my column started with 2, however fist array is a 0, and i had 3 columns, so basicaly this is what i did:

```
    function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl ('my url');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("new project")
  var v1 = sheet.getLastRow()
  Logger.log(v1);
  var v2 = sheet.getLastColumn()
  Logger.log(v2);
  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1 , sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  Logger.log(data);
  for (var i = 2; i <= data.length+1; ++i) 
  {
    var data1 = sheet.getRange(i,1,1,13).getValues()
    Logger.log(i);
    Logger.log(data1); 
    Logger.log(data[i-2][8])
    var cell= data [i-2][9]
      if ( cell ==="") {
          Logger.log('blank cell');
    
  }  
  }
}
```

[execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLnLA.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    //the length keeps you from thinking zeroes are blank
    if(!r[8] && !r[8].toString().length) {
      Logger.log('blank cell');
    }
  });
}
```

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  for(let i = 0;i < vs.length;i++) {
    if(!vs[i][8] && !vs[i][8].toString().length) {
      Logger.log('blank cell')
    }
  }
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
}
```

Sheet1:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 11 | 13 | 2 | 15 | 8 | 7 | 3 | 4 | 7 |
| 13 | 19 | 8 | 16 | 6 | 17 | 11 | 8 |  | 1 |
| 18 | 1 | 14 | 11 | 0 | 11 | 19 | 1 | 15 | 2 |
| 4 | 12 | 12 | 6 | 15 | 9 | 10 | 17 | 10 | 11 |
| 10 | 8 | 2 | 17 | 9 | 16 | 14 | 5 |  | 15 |
| 7 | 14 | 15 | 13 | 12 | 18 | 18 | 18 | 19 | 19 |
| 15 | 14 | 13 | 5 | 10 | 7 | 19 | 9 | 12 | 9 |
| 19 | 13 | 8 | 7 | 4 | 18 | 13 | 10 |  | 11 |
| 13 | 14 | 15 | 6 | 17 | 2 | 8 | 17 | 0 | 12 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 12 | 10 | 12 | 16 | 3 |
| 13 | 13 | 7 | 6 | 19 | 8 | 10 | 11 | 17 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 | 11 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 16 | 18 | 13 |
| 4 | 15 | 4 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 16 | 16 | 9 | 18 |
| 11 | 3 | 3 | 14 | 7 | 15 | 7 | 6 | 0 | 12 |
| 19 | 10 | 1 | 13 | 14 | 1 | 9 | 13 | 8 | 3 |
| 4 | 10 | 18 | 5 | 16 | 19 | 14 | 11 | 0 | 13 |
| 11 | 10 | 7 | 14 | 19 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 11 | 11 |
| 0 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 18 | 3 | 0 | 12 | 4 | 16 |
| 0 | 11 | 0 | 4 | 11 | 7 | 0 | 4 | 13 | 0 |
| 7 | 9 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 11 | 0 | 6 | 10 | 3 |

vs:

```
[[10,11,13,2,15,8,7,3,4,7],
[13,19,8,16,6,17,11,8,"",1],
[18,1,14,11,0,11,19,1,15,2],
[4,12,12,6,15,9,10,17,10,11],
[10,8,2,17,9,16,14,5,"",15],
[7,14,15,13,12,18,18,18,19,19],
[15,14,13,5,10,7,19,9,12,9],
[19,13,8,7,4,18,13,10,"",11],
[13,14,15,6,17,2,8,17,0,12],
[2,3,5,1,1,12,10,12,16,3],
[13,13,7,6,19,8,10,11,17,5],
[6,6,11,1,2,4,4,16,18,13],
[4,15,4,7,7,8,16,16,9,18],
[11,3,3,14,7,15,7,6,0,12],
[19,10,1,13,14,1,9,13,8,3],
[4,10,18,5,16,19,14,11,0,13],
[11,10,7,14,19,3,4,4,11,11],
[0,2,4,1,18,3,0,12,4,16],
[0,11,0,4,11,7,0,4,13,0],
[7,9,0,3,3,11,0,6,10,3]]
```

Comment: used your if, but i still have error: "TypeError: Cannot read property '8' of undefined"